# BDD Cucumber test management tool

Tags: testing, automation, cucumber, open-source, bdd

Is there an open source tool available to control the running of BDD cucumber tests?

We are developing BDD cucumber tests and would like the option to control the tests when running them (start/stop/pause/restart) using an open source (or proprietary) test tool.

Comment: You can use CI server like Jenkins, team city. Bamboo to trigger cucumber test and view report. Also those are provided with cucumber plugins for report. You configure the job on Jenkins (open source tool) to execute cucumber test with maven.

Comment: We are already using a job Jenkins to start the cucumber tests which then run through from start to finish. I don't believe there is functionality in Jenkins to pause and then restart a test, or is there?

Comment: I think you need to expand your question to explain why you feel you need this stuff. Cucumber itself has the ability to start tests, you can use ctrl c to stop tests. I'm not sure why you'd want to pause a suite of tests, but for individual ones you can just debug.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer it, yes.

The somewhat longer answer is that it depends on your echo system.

If you are using Java, then any build tool will be sufficient. That is Maven, Gradle or similar. These are easy to integrate in your Continuous Integration, CI, environment. With a tool chain like that, you are able to execute Cucumber on every build and will always know if your system works or not.

Comment: We are already using a job Jenkins to start the cucumber tests which then run through from start to finish. I don't believe there is functionality in Jenkins to pause and then restart a test, or is there?

Comment: No, why should you? An execution will either pass or fail. When it failed, fix the software and rerun the execution. A developer can run smaller parts in their dev environment and will probably do so during the development.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , but in small scope (Automation tests) and less process control related to run and control tests ,In high scope with multiple branches and projects i think you have to move to Jenkins with full control.

Following link describe the coparsion : https://www.saashub.com/compare-jenkins-vs-cucumber